# OnsenUI：スプリットビューとナビゲーターの併用時のアニメーションについて

Tags: onsen-ui

Onsen UIとPhoneGapを利用してアプリを作成しています。（Monaca不使用）
トップページを`ons-split-view`、
スプリットビューのメインページとして呼ばれるページに`ons-navigator`を配置しています。
（やりたいこととしては、iPadの「設定」のような、左側のメニューは固定・右側のページはアニメで遷移するようなデザインです）

この状態でナビゲーターを利用したスライドアニメ付きのページ遷移
`ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage(hoge.html, { animation: "slide" })`
を行うと、遷移自体は正常に行われるものの、
スライドした遷移前のページがスプリットビューの左側の画面（secondary-page）に被ります
（popPageした時も同様です）。

左側のメニューは常に最前面に配置しておきたいのですが、どうすればいいのでしょうか。
重ね順で何とかできないかとCSSのz-indexを指定してみましたが効果はありませんでした。
解決方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらお教えください。

Comment: 解決策を質問内に記載する代わりにご自身で回答として投稿・承認していただけないでしょうか。他の方にも解決したことがわかりやすくなるかと思います。

Comment: ご指摘の通りにさせて頂きました。コメントありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。
CSSに下記コードを追加することで正常に動作するようになりました。

```
.onsen-split-view__main {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```